# php echo html tag so it is viewable (not interpreted as code)

Tags: php, html, tags, echo

I am currently trying to echo a text value from a variable which contains html-style tags. **<...>**

```
$string = "variable_name";
$tag_str = "<".$string.">";
echo $tag_str;
```

currently this echo's as nothing as it believes it is html code. How would I go about echoing `<variable_name>` to the page so it is **viewable** and not interpreted as code by the browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to html encode your output

```
$string = "variable_name";
$tag_str = "<".$string.">";
echo htmlspecialchars($tag_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The angle brackets (`<>`) are precisely what tells the browser that it *should* be treated as HTML code.  Instead, output the HTML-encoded versions of those otherwise special characters:

```
$tag_str = "&lt;".$string."&gt;";
```

Alternatively, automate this process:

```
$tag_str = htmlspecialchars("<".$string.">");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `highlight_string()`.See below code

```
$string = "variable_name";
$tag_str = "<".$string.">";
highlight_string($tag_str);
```