# fail in adding numeric values to characters on speical characters

Tags: php, ascii

I have this function:

```
function dec($dec)
{
    $ans="";
    for($x=0; $x<strlen($dec);$x++)
    {
        $tempAscii = ord(substr($dec,$x,1)) - ($x+1)*2; //((int)dec[x] - (x+1)*2)
        while ($tempAscii <0) $tempAscii+=256;
        echo $tempAscii,", ";
        $ans = $ans . chr($tempAscii); 
    }
    return $ans;
}
echo "dec, ", dec($_GET['word']);
```

for example, those dec results are just fine:

```
input: as output: _o middle output: 95, 111
input: SHA256 output: QD;*+* middle output:  81, 68, 59, 42, 43, 42
```

But when I'm trying this input, I got something strange:

```
input: $@SHA256*!# output: " middle output: 34, 60, 77, 64, 55, 38, 39, 38, 24, 13, 13
```

I'm not sure if the reason I get this output is because I'm doing a mistake in my function, or there is other reason. Why I got `"` as the last result? thanks.

EDIT: I'm using firefox to see the results.
EDIT: It seems that `<`is the problem. It seems that firefox take this as "smaller then"... How can I change it to be just `>` char without any meaning?

Comment: Is this output from a console or view through a webbrowser? 60 is the ASCII-Character for `<`, so the browser might be trying to interpret that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Comment: @kyeiti via firefox browser. What do you mean by that? I can't represent < in ascii?

Comment: @Faraz I don't understand why this question is helping me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
as @kyeiti mention before, the browser trying to interpret this string as code.

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315406/php-echo-html-tag-so-it-is-viewable-not-interpreted-as-code) I solved this by using the command `htmlspecialchars`. So now my code is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(enc($_GET['word']));
```

many thanks!

Comment: thanks for the information. I am trying it almost 2 hours. But I can't find any solution.